# How to set the background colour in spinner?

Tags: android, spinner

I am using the customised spinner. 
Every item of spiner will be TextView with Height and width set to wrap_Content property. I have also set the background colour of both the spiner and the textview to same colour code in hexadecimal.

My problem is- colour is  visible only upto the area in which text is written and the remaining area is visible as white .

Can anyone tell me what property needs to be set so that no white portion will be visible.
[image: Spinner Image]

Below is layout for each spinner item -

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:textsize="14sp"
 >
```

Spinner item is described in main layout as

```
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spiner"
    android:background="#00ffff"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    />
```

Can anyone suggest what needs to be done to set the background colour properly. I have attached the image showing the problem area as well

Comment: If this customized spinner then give background to parent layout in which your TextView will be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this :

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to this :

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

In your `TextView`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#00ffff"
android:textsize="14sp"
>
```

The change is:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
```

Comment: I agree, this should work.! Or just give background color to the parent of that textView if there is any.

Comment: If this answer is correct please mark it as accepted. More info: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Progammatically :

```
spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.yourcolor);
```

Comment: this required api level 16, is there any procedure for api level 14?

Answer (score 0):

For custom spinner,

have a style , Say bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#FFAA00"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

In your code,

```
sp1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

 sp1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                sp1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg);
                return true;
            }
        });
```